# What package manager does the gitlab docker CI image use?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to install additional software but `apt-get` is not available.

So in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have:

`image: docker:stable`

What is the image based off from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Seems it's just a reference to the above... Which uses APK as the package manager